# When a user request a link in ASP.NET MVC. Where it handle first? web.config or Global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know Global.asax file first handel the incoming request in asp.net mvc and web.config file contain the configuration the application. My query is which is first handle request Global.asax or web.config.

Comment: Web config doesn't handle requests; it's is used during startup and running of the app, to store configuration. If it is corrupt, app wont start, but that doesn't mean it's anything to do with serving a request; just that request is causing app to start and app start is reading config

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow!

You should know more about ASP.NET MVC Life Cycle

The application life cycle refers to the time at which the application process actually begins running IIS until the time it stops. This is marked by the application start and end events in the startup file of your application.

Check this link [Lifecycle of an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application). There is a pdf that charts the lifecycle of every ASP.NET MVC 5 application.